# display firebase data on a flatlist

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display a bunch of data i have on firebase in a flatlist, I don't really know where the problem is right now, i've tried physically filling the array out and that works but it doesn't when i get the data from firebase. I do see that im getting the data on the console log but it's not getting displayed.

```
function Squad() {
  const gk = [];

  db.collection('squad').orderBy('position').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const playerObject = doc.data();
      gk.push({name: playerObject.name, number: playerObject.number});
      console.log(gk);
    });
  });

  const Item = ({ name, number }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>{number} - {name}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item name={item.name} number={item.number} />
  )

  return(
    <View>
      <View style={styles.bar}>
        <Text style={styles.barText}>goalkeeper</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList 
        data={gk}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'll bet get() is async. Put your db call in useEffect, then rebuild when you get results.

Comment: i've never used useEffect, how would that work?

Comment: [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) You'll put your db call inside useEffect, then trigger a rebuild when you get results.

Comment: I tried using useEffect and it's still not working

Comment: Show me what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a useEffect hook to act as a componentWillMount function to call the method when the compnent is ready. I have also included **catch block** in order to show any errors that might occur.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Squad = () => {
  const [gk, setGK] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSquadData();
  });

  const getSquadData = () => {
    db.collection("squad")
      .orderBy("position")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let myData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const playerObject = doc.data();
          myData.push({
            id: playerObject.id,
            name: playerObject.name,
            number: playerObject.number,
          });
        });
        setGK(myData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting data: ", error);
      });
  };

  const Item = ({ name, number }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>
        {number} - {name}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item name={item.name} number={item.number} />
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.bar}>
        <Text style={styles.barText}>goalkeeper</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={gk}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Squad;
```

So if you are seeing error logs in your console, check your collection in firestore, and also check the rules in your firestore.

Comment: I have the code working now I think but I get an error now saying the item.id in the keyextractor in the flatlist is not recognized. I've added an id field to my firestore data and im also getting it now but it's still not working

Comment: Ok, so I have editted the code now, we had forgotten to set the ID (`id: playerObject.id`) in the GK array as well. In future reference, try to console log the array or other variables to see their values to debug easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the info on mount in an async function, then store it in a stateful array using hooks.

```
function Squad() {
  const [gk, setGk] = useState([]);

  const getSquad = async () => {
    const ref = db.collection('squad').orderBy('position');
    const doc = await ref.get();
    const playerObject = doc.data();
    const newGk = [...gk, {name: playerObject.name, number: playerObject.number}];
    setGk(newGk);
  }

 useEffect(() => {
  getSquad();
 }, [])

  const Item = ({ name, number }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>{number} - {name}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item name={item.name} number={item.number} />
  )

  return(
    <View>
      <View style={styles.bar}>
        <Text style={styles.barText}>goalkeeper</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList 
        data={gk}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```